# WPF: Cannot access inner Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a problem with an inner Element in WPF. Its the innerGrid DataGrid. 
I have no access to it in the code behind only to the normal Datagrid. Have I forgotten to add something in the xaml-code?

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = data, IsAsync=True}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="198" Margin="35,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="474" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Expanded="Expander_Expanded" Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed">
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
           <DataGrid x:Name="innerGrid" Height="200">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Patientennummer" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
               </DataTemplate>
             </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
             </DataGrid>
```

Comment: What happens if you try to access it as 'innerGrid'`?

Comment: He will not be able to access it from code behind as its present inside data template.

Comment: When i try to access it i get this error : The name "innerGrid" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Why do you think you need to get to it? Whatever you're doing can almost certainly be done better in XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access inner grid in LoadingRowDetails event of your main "dataGrid".

```
private void dataGrid_LoadingRowDetails(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid innerGrid = e.DetailsElement as DataGrid;

        if (innerGrid != null)
        {
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can add "Loaded" event for "inner grid" and inside this event handler, you can do whatever you want to with inner grid.

Hope this helps.